# Extract one by one values from multiple lists and stored in to new LIST - Python

Tags: python

Extract one by one values from multiple lists and stored in to new LIST - Python

```
List1 = ('1', '2','3','4')

List2 = ('one', 'two','three','four')

List3 = ('1-1', '1-2','1-3','1-4')



output_list = ('1,one,1-1', '2,two,1-2','3,three,1-3','4,four,1-4')
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please add some code snippets and read the guideline [How do I ask a good question? ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use zip

```py
List1 = ('1', '2','3','4')

List2 = ('one', 'two','three','four')

List3 = ('1-1', '1-2','1-3','1-4')

output_list = [f'{l1},{l2},{l3}' for l1, l2, l3 in zip(List1, List2, List3)]
```